# HTML tableheadercell with fixed width doesn't behave accordingly

Tags: html, css, fixed-width

I've set width 180px in the "Site ID" tableheadercell in the table below, but it doesn't behave accordingly. Any idea of the reason why and how I could fix it?
(you can run the snippet to see what I mean)

```html
        <table id="MainContent_tbEdit" class="tbEdit-table" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #868583;text-align:center;padding:8px;">
 <tr id="MainContent_th_Row" style="background-color:#5D7B9D;text-align:center;vertical-align:center;color:white;border:1px solid #868583;">
  <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Scope</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;width:180px;">Site ID</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Site Name</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Address</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">CAP/ZIP</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">City</th><th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Country</th>
 </tr><tr id="MainContent_trz1" style="background-color:#F7F6F2;">
  <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope1-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope1-0">
   <option selected="selected" value="1">EMEA</option>
   <option value="2">APAC</option>
   <option value="3">AMER</option>

  </select></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid1-1">BA002</span></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname1-2" type="text" value="pippo pluto                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    " id="MainContent_tbxSname1-2" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress1-3" type="text" value="kjhjkfs" id="MainContent_tbxAddress1-3" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap1-4" type="text" value="67367346        " id="MainContent_tbxCap1-4" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity1-5" type="text" value="Checco" id="MainContent_tbxCity1-5" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry1-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry1-6">

  </select></td>
 </tr><tr id="MainContent_trz2">
  <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope2-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope2-0">
   <option value="1">EMEA</option>
   <option value="2">APAC</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="3">AMER</option>

  </select></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid2-1">BV001</span></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname2-2" type="text" value="ipoipoi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        " id="MainContent_tbxSname2-2" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress2-3" type="text" value="asdjnjn" id="MainContent_tbxAddress2-3" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap2-4" type="text" value="12398           " id="MainContent_tbxCap2-4" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity2-5" type="text" value="Zorro" id="MainContent_tbxCity2-5" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry2-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry2-6">

  </select></td>
 </tr><tr id="MainContent_trz3" style="background-color:#F7F6F2;">
  <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope3-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope3-0">
   <option value="1">EMEA</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="2">APAC</option>
   <option value="3">AMER</option>

  </select></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid3-1">CK001</span></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname3-2" type="text" value="alkdjkj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        " id="MainContent_tbxSname3-2" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress3-3" type="text" value="jchalsjij" id="MainContent_tbxAddress3-3" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap3-4" type="text" value="1293898         " id="MainContent_tbxCap3-4" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity3-5" type="text" value="Ripotto" id="MainContent_tbxCity3-5" /></td><td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry3-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry3-6">
  </select></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Many thanks.
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Just add `table` style to `table-layout: fixed;`

```html
<table id="MainContent_tbEdit" class="tbEdit-table" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #868583;text-align:center;padding:8px;table-layout: fixed; ">
  <tr id="MainContent_th_Row" style="background-color:#5D7B9D;text-align:center;vertical-align:center;color:white;border:1px solid #868583;">
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Scope</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;width:180px;">Site ID</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Site Name</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Address</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">CAP/ZIP</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">City</th>
    <th scope="column" style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="MainContent_trz1" style="background-color:#F7F6F2;">
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope1-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope1-0">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">EMEA</option>
        <option value="2">APAC</option>
        <option value="3">AMER</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid1-1">BA002</span></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname1-2" type="text" value="pippo pluto                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "
        id="MainContent_tbxSname1-2" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress1-3" type="text" value="kjhjkfs" id="MainContent_tbxAddress1-3" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap1-4" type="text" value="67367346        " id="MainContent_tbxCap1-4" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity1-5" type="text" value="Checco" id="MainContent_tbxCity1-5" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry1-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry1-6">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="MainContent_trz2">
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope2-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope2-0">
        <option value="1">EMEA</option>
        <option value="2">APAC</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">AMER</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid2-1">BV001</span></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname2-2" type="text" value="ipoipoi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "
        id="MainContent_tbxSname2-2" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress2-3" type="text" value="asdjnjn" id="MainContent_tbxAddress2-3" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap2-4" type="text" value="12398           " id="MainContent_tbxCap2-4" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity2-5" type="text" value="Zorro" id="MainContent_tbxCity2-5" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry2-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry2-6">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="MainContent_trz3" style="background-color:#F7F6F2;">
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScope3-0" id="MainContent_ddlScope3-0">
        <option value="1">EMEA</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">APAC</option>
        <option value="3">AMER</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><span id="MainContent_lblSid3-1">CK001</span></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxSname3-2" type="text" value="alkdjkj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "
        id="MainContent_tbxSname3-2" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxAddress3-3" type="text" value="jchalsjij" id="MainContent_tbxAddress3-3" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCap3-4" type="text" value="1293898         " id="MainContent_tbxCap3-4" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxCity3-5" type="text" value="Ripotto" id="MainContent_tbxCity3-5" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;padding:8px;border:1px solid #868583;">
      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCountry3-6" id="MainContent_ddlCountry3-6">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```